# Query fields based on object names

Tags: soql

Is there a way to join FieldDefinition and Entitydefinition?
I would like to run a query like below but it is not working

`select id, DataType, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition a , EntityDefinition b JOIN a.EntityDefinitionId = b.DurableId WHERE b.QualifiedApiName IN ('Case','Attachment')`

Comment: Your query will work if you execute it via Tooling API. Remove the extra comma after `DeveloperName`

Comment: extra comma was a typo. Tooling API is not an option unfortunately, ideally I need a way to join EntityDefinition and FieldDefinition to get QualifiedApiName in the query result, so something like `select id, DataType, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition a , EntityDefinition b
JOIN a.EntityDefinitionId = b.DurableId
WHERE b.QualifiedApiName IN ('Case','Attachment')`
but this does not work

Comment: The SOQL statement in your question works for us when executed via regular SOQL (not Tooling). The SOQL statement in your comments is a different issue. Instead of using comments, please edit your question (see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)) and clarify your goals. SOQL is not SQL, it doesn't work the way you think. You might be able to get what you're after via a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm).